# Interpretation of "share in" in "shared in the ongoing tragedy"

Tags: meaning

> “Although northern Carolina, unlike the colony’s southern reaches, did
>   not at first import large numbers of African slaves, both regions
>   **shared in** the ongoing tragedy of bloody relations between Indians and Europeans."
>
> From "The American Pageant" by Thomas A. Bailey

I have checked the thread https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125385/difference-between-to-share-in-and-to-share

I think the writer is using "share **in**" because northern Carolina and southern Carolina were not the only two regions that participated in the war against Indians(bloody relations). There were other regions, or other Europeans than the British who colonized Carolina.  Is my interpretation correct?

Post 3 in https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/shared-in-shared-the-ongoing-tragedy.3586949/#post-18251878 seems to agree with my interpretation.

> "I don't see any difference in this particular example, but in a more
>   general context:
>
> ... they would share the blame. "They" would be to blame. They would
>   be the only people to blame,
>
> ... they would share in the blame. "They" would take some of the
>   blame. They, and **others not identified**, would be to blame. "

Comment: Is there any particular reason you doubt your interpretation?

Comment: No particular reason. As a non-native speaker，I  feel unsure whether I am correct with my interpretation.  I hope  for your confirmation or correction.

Comment: I'd interpret this the same way. Without the "in" it could be interpreted that they were the only two regions which experienced the tragedy. (It would, however, not rule this out entirely.)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, Bee.  :)  Well, at least, I know I am not the only one  who have such an interpretation.